# Refresh Developer Edition

Tags: developer-edition

I signed up for a [Developer Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup) but want to start from fresh as though I've just signed up. **This isn't associated with any production account,** so I can't refresh from production for example which are the only resources I could find.

I've only managed to do this by associating that org with another e-mail account and re-registering although this seems really inefficient to do something as simple as refreshing to a clean slate.

Is this possible or is the way I've done it the only way?

Comment: Developer edition org can't be refreshed. There is no standard way.

Comment: You shouldn't feel too bad about signing up for multiple dev orgs, a lot of people have magnitudes of them.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke True, it's a personal org though and more just for keeping things organised associated with my address. Of course, I could've signed up with a different username as well but I'd rather just keep things as simple as possible. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ashwani said:

> Developer edition org can't be refreshed. There is no standard way.

However, I did find an idea listed on the [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000IedNAAS), "Reset Developer Account to vanilla state", which is currently set at *PRODUCT TEAM REVIEW*.

Looks like it's something they're investigating (hopefully) planning to implement.